# Calculating depth of a node of a tree with certain constraints in C++

Tags: c++

I have a tree in which there are 3 levels. There is a root node, the root node has 3 leaf nodes and all 3 leaf nodes have 3 other leaf nodes. The nodes represent servers. Now, I have to calculate the depth of a node at for a given level. The depth is calculated as follows:

1) If a server(node) is "up" at any level and any column, then the depth of that node is 0.

2) If a server is in the last level and is "down", then depth of that node is infinity.

3) For all other cases, the depth of the node is the max depth of it's leaf nodes + 1. By max depth, it means the majority value that has occurred in it's child nodes.

A bottom up approach is followed here and hence, the depth of the root node is the depth at level 1. The level is taken as the input parameter in the program. Now, I have to calculate the depth of the root node.

I have made some assumptions regarding the program:

1) To find child nodes, follow the child pointer of the parent node.

2) To find all nodes in a given level, traverse the child nodes from root till I reach that level and make a list of them.

3) Assign the values according to the given constraints.

I am not sure whether my approach is right or not. Please help me guys. Thank you.

Comment: I assume for the first constraint, you meant "If a server _is in the last level_ and is up", correct?

Comment: No, for the first constraint, no matter at what level the server is, if it is up, then the depth of that node is 0. For example, if the node is at level 2 and column 4 and if it is up, then the depth of that node is 0. I edited the question.

Comment: I'm struggling to fully understand the problem you're trying to solve here. Could you give more background to the problem. Also, would it not the be the case that if any node is 'down' then the root node will have a depth of `infinity`?

Comment: I understand your point. By max (leaf nodes), I meant the value which majority of the leaf nodes has. For example, if there is a node which has 3 leaf nodes having values infinity, 1, 1. Then the maxdepth of that node will be 1 because two of it's leaf nodes have the value 1. Nevertheless, there can be a case where the root node has the value infinity. In that case, the whole network is a failure.

Comment: Ok, for a minute there, I thought I was beginning to understand.  The logic for a given node looks like this:  "If I'm up, return 0.  If I'm down but have children, return 1 + max(depth(children)).  If I'm down and have no children, return Infinity."  But then you said max(infinity, 1) = 1 and I was confused again.

Comment: Maybe you'd do better trying to explain the higher level goal of the algorithm, and not the constraints you've constructed.  I suspect, for example, you want 'min' instead of 'max', and the problem is to find "minimum distance from root to a node that's not down."

Comment: Just tell us what your application/problem is and this context will make it easier to understand what you are trying to do. So far I think you have 9 leaves, 3 intermediate nodes and a root node (ternary tree of depth three). I then think you want to report the mode status of the nodes below a given node. I feel therefore that your use of the word depth in the title of the question is misleading. I would also ask why you have chosen the value infinity for a bad node, surely -1 would be less confusing and easier to deal with in code too.

Comment: @Choc13: -1 can be taken for better understanding of the code. Here, the depth of each node is not the sum of it's child nodes + 1. The depth here is the value of the majority of the child nodes of a particular node + 1.

Comment: Shouldn't a node that is up return a value of 1? Otherwise how do leaf nodes gain a value of 1?

Comment: @Choc13: If a node is up, no matter at which level it is, then the value is always 0. That is the first constraint. If suppose, a node is in the 2nd level and it has 3 child nodes having depths 0, 0, infinity. Then that node has a value of 1 because two of it's children are having the value 0 and if we add 1 to it, then the depth comes 0 + 1 = 1.

Comment: @Joe: The logic what I meant is: "If I'm up, return 0. If I'm down and have no children, return Infinity. If I'm down but have children, return 1 + (child nodes having the value which occurs the most)". For example, let us suppose a node A has 5 child nodes having depths infinity, 0, 0, 0, infinity. Then here the value 0 is occurring in most of the child nodes of A. So, we take the depth of node A as 0 + 1 = 1. I hope it is bit clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something along the lines of the following pseudocode:

```
int nodeStatus(const Node& n) {
    int status = 0;
    if (n.isUp)
        return 1;
    else if (n.isLeaf)
        return -1;
    else {
        for (Node child : n.children) 
            status += nodeStatus(child);
    }
    if (status > 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

This is a recursive method. It first checks if the node is up, in which case it returns 1. Then if the node is down and is a leaf it returns -1 as this is a failure with no children. Finally, if `n` is an intermediate node then it recursively calls this method again for all the children, summing the result. The final `if` statement then tests whether the majority of the children are classed as 1 or -1 and returns the value accordingly. Notice that by using the values `1` and `-1` it's possible to just sum the children up and providing each node definitely has `3` (or an odd number of) nodes then there will never be a situation where `status == 0` which would be the case where there is no majority case.

You will need to define a `struct` called `Node` somewhere that looks like this:

```
struct Node {
    Node(bool isUp, bool isLeaf);
    bool isUp;
    bool isLeaf;
    std::Vector<Node> children = new std::Vector<Node>(3);
}
```

I hope this answers your question, but it may be that I've interpreted it wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much for your code. I have few things to add to this. Also, I have few questions. Firstly, if a node is up, then it always returns 0. "Then if the node is down and is a leaf it returns -1 as this is a failure with no children.". This is correct. My question is where are we getting the majority of the values of the child nodes here? We don't want to sum up the values of the child nodes, we just want to take the majority of the values. That value, added by 1, would make the depth of the parent node.

Comment: Also, I need to take the level as the input parameter. The level is an integer value so that while running the program, if I give 2 as the level, then the program will return the depth of the node at level 2.

Comment: Does a node that is up need to have a value of 0 or is this an arbitrary design choice you have made? The reason to have 1 instead of 0 is for symmetry with the -1 for a failed node. This way when we sum over the three children to get `status` which is defined by the set `{-3, -1, 1, 3}` for a ternary tree and the final `if \ else` statement tests which side of 0 `status` is on and returns `1` or `-1` accordingly, hence getting the majority (modal) value of the children.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you mean by `depth`. You state you want the depth of a node to be `1 + majority(children)` if it has failed and has children, but `0` otherwise. This means that a node in the middle layer or our three-level tree can have a value of `1`. Is this value then what should be used when calculating the depth of its parents? I.e. could the `root` node have a depth of 2 under the conditions where 2 of the 3 node in the 2nd layer have failed, but have depths of `1`? I think you need to define depth better, more context of the problem would be helpful.

Comment: That is the requirement given by the project. The depth could be calculated in a method say CalculateDepth(Graph), we can then store the levels in a list for example, and get the depth of the nodes in another method getDepth(level) where level is the input parameter.

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct. The root will have depth of 2 in that case.

Comment: I don't think you constraints are self-consistent then. If you want a node that is down with children to return the majority score of it's children, but in some cases the children can take on any real number and in others they are binary valued, then how can this be achieved? It seems something is missing, such as the definition of depth is incorrect. I think you need to include the full text of the problem you have been set by editing your question. It's OK to post HW questions on SO and ask for suggestions, but you just won't get a full solution. This is the same for any question though.

Comment: Are you trying to find the mode of their child values, or do you want to know how far from the bottom of the tree they are? Or some combination of both? Also, wanting the level as input to this method doesn't work, there are multiple node on all but the top level, so how do you know which node you want to return the depth for in that said level? The input must be a `Node` as we are calculating a property of a `Node` not a level as a whole.

Comment: I think as of now, your code is Ok for this situation. I will try to work further with this code.